# otp_code: wrong number of arguments in recent update of active_model_otp gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I updated my Gemfile and rotp (4.1.0) and active_model_otp(1.2.0) gems got updated. Since then I've start getting error while calling @user.otp_code method associated with User modal "wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)"

```
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rotp-4.1.0/lib/rotp/totp.rb:17:in `at' 
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/active_model_otp-1.2.0/lib/active_model/one_time_password.rb:77:in `otp_code' 
    /home/app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb:745:in `resetpassword'
```

as far as I dig into it, I found this.
the issue is in arguments, it seems the latest rotp gem have updated below method to accept only 1 argument insted of 2 as compared to older version (3.3.1)

since the optional parameter has been removed, the active_model_otp-1.2.0 gem is giving error at line number 77

as per rotp-4.1.0

```
    def at(time)
        generate_otp(timecode(time))
    end
```

as per rotp-3.3.1

```
    def at(time, padding=true)
        unless time.class == Time
            time = Time.at(time.to_i)
        end   
        generate_otp(timecode(time), padding)
    end
```

I tried making changes in the gem as below

```
    def otp_code(options = {})
     if otp_counter_based
        if options[:auto_increment]
          self.otp_counter += 1
          save if !new_record?
        end
        ROTP::HOTP.new(otp_column, digits: otp_digits).at(self.otp_counter)
      else
        if options.is_a? Hash
          time = options.fetch(:time, Time.now)
          padding = options.fetch(:padding, true)
        else
          time = options
          padding = true
        end
       # ROTP::TOTP.new(otp_column, digits: otp_digits).at(time, padding)
       # -- Commented Above Line to remove padding arguments from it.
        ROTP::TOTP.new(otp_column, digits: otp_digits).at(time)
      end
    end
```

it worked but not sure what else will break, active-model gem was last updated in 2015, and rotp updated few months back.
please suggest suitable method, if I revert back to previous gem version of rotp then what else would break. I'm kind of stuck.

kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like if you want to use `active_model_otp` gem you'll have to downgrade `rotp` as suggested in the [opened issue](https://github.com/heapsource/active_model_otp/issues/480). Not sure if it breaks anything, probably it won't since it worked previously for you.

Seems like they don't rush to fix it, perhaps you can create a PR with a fix so that maybe they accept it.
Another option is to fork their repo, fix it and publish as your own gem to use it instead.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'm taking it up with active-model-otp team, they should lock the rotp gem version to 3.3.0

https://github.com/heapsource/active_model_otp/issues/48#issuecomment-465454039

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the above issue by locking the rotp gem to 3.3.1 version.

Steps to Follow:

1) Update gem file with 
gem 'rotp', '~> 3.3.0'

2) Take a backup of Gemfile.lock to Gemfile-backup-xx-xx-xxx.lock

3) run bundle install.